# Deleting DefaultController gives Exception DefaultController does not exist

Tags: routes, symfony

I noticed that if I remove the file `DefaultController`, I get an error like "[1/2] ReflectionException: Class .../DefaultController does not exist". If I add it back even without any actions, it works. Isit possible to remove/rename the Default controller?

I tried modifing my routes.yml to look like

```
NotesBundle:
    resource: "@NotesBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    defaults: { _controller: NotesBundle:Notes:list }
```

to try to use `NotesController:listAction` as the default action, but it gives the same error. I suppose I am doing it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be two reasons it fails when you remove/rename a controller:

1. It's being referenced from some part of your system.
2. If not, probably it's the cache that you forgot to clear.

Comment: And if still not. Don't forget the actual controller's name is the Class name and not the File name :)